# Extract strings in a .txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I have a .txt file with this structure:

chair  102 
file  38  
green  304 
...  ...

It has 140.000 elements.

Before introducing the numbers I used javascript and jQuery:

```
$(function () {
        $.get('/words.txt', function (data) {
            words = data.split('\n');

        });
```

But because I have now numbers how could I treat separately the strings and the numbers?

Comment: It's not the soulution I'm looking for because I need two distinct variables for each line

Comment: Your structure is not clear. My understanding is `<word><space><num>\n` You split on new line, so now you have an array of `<word><space><num>` which you should be able to split on space.

Comment: OK thank you. I didn't create the file so I've just checked it and found out that your solution is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this helped, I'll post as an answer:

Your format is `<word><space><num>\n`
You split on new line, so now you have an array of `<word><space><num>` which you should be able to split on space.

Then you can get the word part as `myarray[0]` and the number part as `myarray[1]`.

Comment: Ok, I split the first array, then splitting the splitted array ( XD ) gives me a multidimensional array (?) and then to retrieve the nth word and the nth number I do: globalArray[n][0] or globalArray[n][1]

Answer (score 1):

you could split at each new line and then split each element at space, but this will gives you array of array of *words* .

you could replace line with space and then split at space
ie:

```
words = data.replace(/\n/g,' ').split(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way of handling this problem is to replace all the line breaks with spaces, then split the resulting string by the spaces. Then use what you know about the position of the elements to determine whether you're dealing with a number or a string:

```
var resultArr = data.replace(/\n/g, " ").split(" ")

for(var i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {

    if(i % 2) {
        // even indexes represent the word
        console.info("word = " + resultArr[i]);
    } else {
        // odd indexes represent the number 
        console.info("number = " + resultArr[i]);

    }

}
```

Depending on whether or not there's a line break at the end of the set, you may need to handle that case by looking for an empty string.